# c++ singleton class instance access all over application

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a log class with threadsafe practice in c++. Now the thing is, I want to make the call to each log line very simple. I can go with static class way like below:

```
//Calling this in some GUI initialization point of application
CLogger::InitLogger("LogFile.log");

//Calling below from any class just adding the header to the cpp
CLogger::Log("Some informational text goes here");
```

Now this doesn't follow the OOP so would like to go with a singleton class.

```
//Singleton log class
class CLogWrite
{
public:
  static CLogWrite* GetInstance();

private:
  static CLogWrite *pInstance;
  void Log();
};

CLogWrite* CLogWrite::GetInstance()
{
  if(pInstance != NULL)
  {
    pInstance = new CLogWrite;
  }
  return pInstance;
}

void CLogWrite::Log()
{
  //threadSafe lock

  //write 'logText' to file here

  //threadSafe unlock
}
```

Now the thing is, if I write above class and call CLogWriter::GetInstance() inside my GUI class init function like below:

```
//single logger instance for my app
CLogWriter *mLogInstance;
mLogInstance = CLogWriter::GetInstance()
```

I need to pass 'mLogInstance' variable to each and every class inside my project from where I want to write a log. But I don't wanna do that.

What would be best approach?

Comment: why cant you declare as global variable, because in our application we were using as global variable

Comment: "variable to each and every class" . what does this means.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? You can use an existing logging library like [Boost.log](http://www.boost.org/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) or [glog](https://github.com/google/glog).

Comment: Global variable is the quickest thing came to my mind. But that also breaking the rules of OOP. Variable to each and every class - this means. In an application project I have several class. Say one main GUI class along with several worker class. i.e. CFileReadWrite, CSocketDataOperation, etc.

Comment: @glog. –  Kerrek.. Well its a general concern of mine. I don't wanna use ready made log class as these codes needs to be run on various platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& getInstance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;
    void operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;

private:
    Singleton() {};        
};
```

Comment: Can you please explain this.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit.

Comment: @PLearner It's well known as [_Scott Meyer's Singleton idiom_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173716/player-obj-error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol-private-static-class-in/25173785?s=2|0.3768#25173785)

Comment: If you call getInstance the first time, instance will be lazy initialized. The Constructor and Copy Constructor is private, so there can be only one instance.

Comment: what is the usage of 'void operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;' ?

Comment: @PLearner These remove the declarations of copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: He wanted thread-safe code. First of all, there was no word about C++ 11, and only this and above standards guarantee initialization of local statics to be thread-safe. Secondly, some compilers still don't support this feature (VC++ 11 to be an example).

Comment: I want my code to be supported on old compilers. Not C++ 11. Currently targetting both VC++ 2005 and 2012.

Comment: If you're going to delete copy constructor and copy assignment operator they should be public, not private. If you don't want to use the C++11 delete keyword and syntax, then they should be private.

With your example, if a use of either of the two functions is detected by the compiler, it will complain about the use of a private function rather than use of a deleted one, which is of course less precise.

Comment: @PLearner Then don't use `= delete` syntax presented above, since it's a C++ 11 feature and it's not supported even in VS2012. Make copy constructor and assignment operator private and don't provide definition for them.

Comment: @Mateusz Grzejek.. Can you show me an example or guide me with my below posted code.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favourite techniques in C++ is so-called [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which can be used to implement singleton logic. Look at this code:

```
template <class Type>
class Singleton
{
private:
    static std::unique_ptr<Type>    _holder_ptr;
    static std::mutex               _mutex;

public:
    static Type& GetSingleton()
    {
        if(!_holder_ptr)
            _create_instance();

        return *(_holder_ptr.get());
    }

protected:
    static void _create_instance()
    {
        _mutex.lock();

        if(!_holder_ptr)
            _holder_ptr.reset(new Type());

        _mutex.unlock();
    }
};
```

Now, you can use this class to define "singletons":

```
class Log : public Singleton<Log>
{
    //content
};
```

and use it:

```
Log& global_log = Log::GetSingleton();
//do something
```

This is version for C++ 11. For older compilers, replace `std::mutex` with platform-dependent synchronizing primitive. On Windows, you may want to use [CRITICAL_SECTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Sample usage: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`std::unique_ptr` was also introduced in C++ 11, so you may either replace it with [std::auto_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/) (deprecated in C++ 11), use [smart pointer from Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) or create your own solution (which is not hard, but reinventing the wheel is not a good idea).

Note, that this `Singleton` does not forbid to create additional instances of `Log` - and it should not! There are two common scenarios:

- You allow users to create additional instances of `Log`, but at the same time demand, that at least one such object must exist. Then, simple deriving from `Singleton` is all what you need.
- You need `Log` to be true "Singleton", that is: only one, shared instance can exist - rest of code must use this instance, so everything can work as expected. In this case, use `= delete` syntax to remove default constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator (or simply declare them as `protected` or `private`, depending on compiler support for `= delete` syntax).

Also, remember, that if you want to hold shared instance as pointer, you need to use some kind of smart pointers, as presented above. You cannot use plain pointers like in your original solution:

```
CLogWrite* CLogWrite::GetInstance()
{
    if(pInstance != NULL)
    {
        pInstance = new CLogWrite;
    }
    return pInstance;
}
```

Where and when `pInstance` would be destroyed? How?

Comment: Thanks for the neat code and its explanation. Now coming to 'Log& global_log = Log::GetSingleton();' - this thing either needs to be a class member or global variable. Isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean? All you need to do is to call `GetSingleton()` every time you need to retrieve global instance of singleton class.

Comment: Oh yes. I got it now.